# How to call Parallel.For with a method of the one instance but different constructor parameters c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, testing, exception

I am investigating a bug and trying to replicate a SQL Exception - `Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index . The duplicate key value. The statement has been terminated`

I am doing this within the unit tests to replicate the exception.

Here is the test:

```
public void Should_Throw_Exception_When_StartExecution_Is_Called_Twice_By_Two_Different_Programs_Belonging_To_Same_Account()
    {
        //Arrange
        var executorContext = new ExecutorContext
        {
            Program = new ProgramObject
            {
                ID = 100,
                Account = RootAccount
            },
            ScheduledExecutionDate = DateTime.Now
        };

        var executorContext2 = new ExecutorContext
        {
            Program = new ProgramObject
            {
                ID = 200,
                Account = RootAccount
            },
            ScheduledExecutionDate = DateTime.Now
        };

        var tracker = new ProgramExecutionTracker(executorContext, _dataContext);

        Parallel.For(0, 5, (i) => tracker.StartExecution());
    }
```

The Parallel.For is meant to call the start execution method multiple times, however I need to pass in two different `executorContext` objects when creating `ProgramExecutionTracker`.

How can I achieve this so that `tracker.StartExecution` is called by multiple threads with different executor contexts?

Answer (score 0):

You could switch back and forth between the two contexts:

```
public void Should_Throw_Exception_When_StartExecution_Is_Called_Twice_By_Two_Different_Programs_Belonging_To_Same_Account()
{
ExecutorContext[] executorContexts= new 
ExecutorContext[2]; //array with 2 elements

    //Arrange
    executorContexts[0] = new ExecutorContext
    {
        Program = new ProgramObject
        {
            ID = 100,
            Account = RootAccount
        },
        ScheduledExecutionDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    executorContexts[1] = new ExecutorContext
    {
        Program = new ProgramObject
        {
            ID = 200,
            Account = RootAccount
        },
        ScheduledExecutionDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    Parallel.For(0, 5, (i) => ((new ProgramExecutionTracker(executorContexts[i%2], _dataContext)) .StartExecution());
}
```